# grep to find files that contain ^M (Windows carriage return)

Tags: grep

I use Linux. There is a pesky ^M (Windows cariage return) somewhere hidden in thousands of configuration files, and I have to find it, because it makes the server fail.

How do I find ^M among a directories hierarchy full of configuration files?

I think I can not enter ^M on the bash command line. But I have it in a text file that I called m.txt

Comment: Related: [Remove carriage return in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/800030/456814).

Comment: windows would be  ^M^J

Comment: "I can not enter ^M on the bash command line". Yes you can. Try control-V Control-M

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```bash
grep -r $'\r' *
```

Use `-r` for recursive search and `$''` for c-style escape in Bash.

Moreover, if you are sure it's a text file, then it should be safe to run

```bash
tr -d $'\r' < filename
```

to remove all `\r` in a file.

If you are using GNU `sed`, `-i` will perform an in-place edit, so you won't need to write the file back:

```bash
sed $'s/\r//' -i filename
```

Comment: @Nicolas: You can enter a ^M at the command line by pressing ^V^M, but it's better to use `$'\r'`.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks for the ^V^M trick too :-)

Comment: Under Cygwin, -U is needed to make this work. And -n will tell you the line number: grep -r -U -n -e $'\r'

Comment: Add an -l to the grep command to just view the filenames.  Else you might be bombarded with matching lines.

Comment: Note that using `\r` in `sed 's/\r//' -i filename` won't work with OS X's version of `sed` (I've read that GNU-sed will recognize it though). As a workaround, `CTRL-V + CTRL-M` seems to work in the place of `\r` instead.

Comment: ¿Can `$'\r'` be somehow inserted inside a greater expression?

Comment: @Cupcake I edited the answer, and use C-style, it should work as long as the shell is Bash.

Comment: @uprego what do you mean by "greater expression?" Could you give a line of example code of what are you trying to do?

Comment: @livibetter I was confused by not knowning (currently don't know yet) the meaning of the dollah glyph in `sed $'s/\r//' -i filename`, use a dollar before a substitution expresion. Never seen it. And I was confused by the uses in `grep -r $'\r' *` and `tr -d $'\r' < filename`, I was matching them to the idiom `join file1 file12 -t $'\t'`, like used in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722353](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722353).

Comment: @uprego not sure if you understand them now, but fyi and other's, search `$'` read the first hit in manpage `bash(1)`, basically, you can see it as if you were writing C literal string. As for the `command < filename`, the use of `<` or `>` is called *redirection*, this is first time I have seen anyone called it *greater expression*. Search `REDIRECTION` in `bash(1)`.

Comment: For those who happen to be using SunOS 5.10 and met with the error grep: illegal option -r , you should use `grep $'\r' *`

Comment: how to exclude searching for \r\n?

Answer (score 15):

When I tried, I could tell it was sort-of working, but the lines were printing blank.  Add in the option:

```
--color=never
```

If you get this issue, I think it's the escape characters for color highlighting interfering with the `\r` character.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know why I was getting blank lines.

Answer (score 3):

If your server does not have a bash shell, an alternative is to use the `-f` option on `grep`, in combination with a prepared file containing `\r`.

To create the file:

```
$ echo -ne '\r' > /tmp/cr                    --or--                   $ printf '\r' > /tmp/cr

$ od -c /tmp/cr
0000000  \r
0000001
```

To actually do the search

```
$ grep -f /tmp/cr *.html *.php *.asp *.whatever
```

or you can be a little lazy and just type *,

```
$ grep -f /tmp/cr *
```

The `-f filename` option on `grep` is used to specify a file that contains patterns to match, one per line. In this case there's only one pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, what you really want is to normalize all line-endings to the Unix LF (`\x0a`) standard. That is not the same as just blindly removing CRs (`\x0d`).

If you happen to have some Mac files around which use just CR for newlines, you will destroy those files. (Yes, Macs are supposed to use LF since almost 20 years, but there are still (in 2019) many Mac apps which use just CR).

You could use Perl's `\R` [linebreak escape](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#%5cR) to replace any sort of newline with `\n`.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\R/\n/g' $your_file
```

This would replace in-place any sort of linebreak with `\n` in `$your_file`, keeping a backup of the original file in `${your_file}.bak`.

Comment: `dos2unix` is the proper command.

Comment: @pbies: Unfortunately, no. `dos2unix` doesn't seem to work in cases of mixed line endings (just re-tested on files with mixed CRLF and CR-only). That was the original reason why I started to use Perl instead. Besides, `dos2unix` needs to be installed, while Perl is already available on any decent Unix system.

Comment: Have you tried binary mode?

Answer (score 1):

To use grep on end-of-line characters, I guess you have to tell grep the file is binary.

- `-l` (letter L) is for printing only the filename
- `-P` is for perl regexp (so `\x0d` is transformed to `\r` or `^M`)

```
grep -l --binary -P '\x0d' *
```

Answer (score 0):

In regular expression style, various newlines:

Windows (CR LF)
`\r\n`

Unix (LF)
`\n`

Since the `\r\n` sequence is fairly unique, I think you should be able to search for it that way?

To make things worse Macs used to have just '\r' in place of newline.
I cannot verify this, but I don't think MacOSX generations does that any more.

Older Macs (CR)
`\r`

Comment: In the directory that contains m.txt, `grep "\r\n" *` gives no result. No result either for `egrep -e "\r\n" *` nor `grep -E "\r\n" *`

Comment: @nicolas ah, I misunderstood.. you meant CR only `\r` my bad. A full windows newline is indeed `\r\n` or CRLF

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac and use [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git), you can do:

```
brew install tofrodos
fromdos file.txt
```

to remove all the Windows carriage returns from **file.txt**

To switch back to Windows carriage returns,

```
todos file.txt
```

Comment: to search in a folder and clean all files coming from dos, run this command : find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs fromdos

Answer (score 0):

Following up on previous answers, the `tr` method is good:

```
533$ if [[ -n "`tr -cd "\r" <~/.bashrc`" ]]; then echo "DOS"; else echo "UNIX"; fi
UNIX

534$ if [[ -n "`tr -cd "\r" <dosfile.txt`" ]]; then echo "DOS"; else echo "UNIX"; fi
DOS
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers require Bash, this one should not:

```
grep -a -r "$(printf '\r')"
```

### Explanation

- `printf '\r'` prints a literal carriage return character
- The wrapping `"$(..)"` puts the CR into an argument to the grep command.
- `-a` tells grep to act on binary files, too, so that it actually prints matching lines even if the file is considered binary.